# Using VLD, Dynamic load DLL failed

Tags: c++, memory-leak-detector

We have a windows Application, some DLLs are dynamic loaded using LoadLibraryW(). These Dlls are put in different Directory。 When we turn on VLD memory leak check, these DLLs failed to load. It seems like not search folders normally when load library. When we turn off VLD, the Application can be Started normally. Is anyone know the reasons? Thanks.

We try to load Dll in the same folder of main application, it can be loaded successfully. But Dlls in children folders can not be loaded。

Comment: Just a guess (as I have never heard of VLD).  Are you using relative path(s) to load the DLLs?  If so this is not reliable as the current working directory may be changed at any time (by any code in the process).  It looks like VLD could be doing this.  Always load DLLs by full absolute path.

Comment: Yes，we use  relative path(s) to load the DLLs。The DLL that cannot be loaded depend many other Dlls，it is difficult to use full absolute path。 Thank you very much。

Comment: Any code in any DLL loaded into your process that uses [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) is going to break your program.  This does not have be code under your control.  It is also a security vulnerability as your program can loose control of the  DLLs. it loads. Usual fix is to use GetModuleFileName to get the path the program and build absolute DLL paths from it.

Comment: It seems a good idea。We will try it later。Thank you very much！